Different results when fitting ARIMA model for levels vs ARMA model for first differences in R
In the following code I show that I get different forecasts when fitting an ARIMA(2,1,0) for cumulative sums of a generated AR(2) model vs. fitting an ARMA(2,0) for the AR(2) itself. Can anyone point me to the error I make?
library(forecast)

# Constructing the series
iN = 2000
vAR2 = rep(NA, iN)
phi1 = 0.2
phi2 = 0.3
vAR2[1] = rnorm(1)
vAR2[2] = phi1 * vAR2[1] + rnorm(1)
for(i in 1 : (iN - 2)){
  vAR2[i + 2] = phi1 * vAR2[i + 1] + phi2 * vAR2[i] + rnorm(1)
}
plot(vAR2, type = "l")
vLevels = cumsum(vAR2)  
plot(vLevels, type = "l")  
  
# Fitting ARIMA for levels
iMW = iN / 2
iNOut = iN - iMW
vLevelsPred = rep(NA, length(vLevels))

for(i in 1 : iNOut){
  oARIMA = arima(x = vLevels[i : (iMW + i - 1)], order = c(2, 1, 0))
  vLevelsPred[iMW + i] = forecast(oARIMA, h = 1)$mean[1]
}

plot(vLevels, type = "l")
lines(vLevelsPred, col = "red")

# Fitting ARMA for first differences
vAR2Pred = rep(NA, length(vAR2))

for(i in 1 : iNOut){
  oARIMAar = arima(x = vAR2[i : (iMW + i - 1)], order = c(2, 0, 0))
  vAR2Pred[iMW + i] = forecast(oARIMAar, h = 1)$mean[1]
}

# Recostructing levels
vAR2Pred[iMW] = vLevels[iMW]
vAR2Pred[is.na(vAR2Pred)] = 0
vLevelsRecPred = cumsum(vAR2Pred)
vLevelsRecPred[vLevelsRecPred == 0] = NA

plot(vLevels)
lines(vLevelsPred, col = "red")
lines(vLevelsRecPred, col = "blue")


You could use set.seed before generating random numbers to ensure everyone gets the exact same result as you do. But probably it is not so important here.

Your loops fit rolling AR(I)MA models. Why do you do that? Can you simplify your code to a single time series and a single fit of the two models that exhibits the behavior you are interested in?
